# C++ - Pushing back a list of queues

Tags: c++, list, queue, addition, element

I've created a list of queues and was wondering how I will be able to push back the queue to add a new element. I have multiples clients to send messages to and the host will send the exact same message to each in a specific order. I currently have it as

```
struct messages
{
    char buffer[64];
}

list<queue<messages>> MessageList;
for(int i = 0; i < numOfClients; i++)
{
    queue<messages> tempQueue;
    MessageList.push_back(tempQueue);
}
list<queue<messages>>::iterator MsgIt;
MsgIt = MessageList.begin();

messages storedMsg = {}
char tempMsg[64] = "This is the message to be stored!";
for(int j = 0; j < 64; j++)
    storedMsg.message[j] = tempMsg[j];
for(int i = 0; i < numOfClients; i++)
{
    *MsgIt.push(storedMsg);
    MsgIt++;
}
```

There appears to be an error in which `*MsgIt` will not allow me to access the `push()` function.

I understand that

```
queue<messages> MessageList;
MessageList.push(Message);
```

will work, but since there is multiple clients receive this message, I wish to use it in a "list of queues" instead of creating 15-20 or so queues which can be hard to manage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `MsgIt->push(Message)` instead of the awkward dereference. The `.` operator has a higher precedence than the `*` operator, so what's happening is that it's trying to call `.` on the iterator rather than what the iterator points to, then trying to dereference the returned value, neither of which are what you want. You'd have to do `(*MsgIt).push` to get the desired result using dereferencing.

Also your use of iterators isn't really how you should do it. It should look like:

```
for(MessageList::iterator MsgIt = MessageList.begin(), MsgIt < MessageList.end(), MsgIt++)
```

Finally, as @ChronoTrigger mentioned, you haven't actually placed any `queue`s in the `MessageList` list, at least in this code. So there is nothing to `push` to in the first place.

Comment: I can never remember if C++ does deep copies of statically allocated arrays or not. It happens. I agree it should be a std::string at the very least to prevent buffer-overflows.

Comment: `MsgIt->push(Message)` worked perfectly. As did `(*MsgIt).push`

Accepted as answer

Answer (score 1):

`*MsgIt` is of type `queue<messages>`, and you are trying to insert a variable of type `char[64]`.

You should insert first a `queue` and then , in the `queue`, your message.

Comment: I've edited the original post to include the initialisation of the queues populating the list which I originally had. But even then I still appear to get errors.

Comment: See my answer for why it will still fail.